# WPF: filling the "gap" in a StackPanel of buttons when removing one of the buttons

Tags: wpf, button, stackpanel

I am defining a StackPanel containing multiple Buttons in my xaml file.  I'd like to be able to remove buttons based on some events, and have the "gap" where that button was be filled by having the following Buttons move up on the screen.

I used:
buttonName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
but that just hides the button and leaves a gap.

Would it be simpler to add the buttons to the StackPanel in the .cs file, and if one button is removed than I just add one less button to my window?  And if so, how do I add a button from the .cs file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `Visibility.Collapsed`